# JAXB @XmlElement Order for List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to generate following XML using JAXB

```
<Data>
    <text lang="en"/>
    <text align="center"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <text>TICKET</text>
    <feed unit="12"/>
    <text align="left"/>
    <text>Order 1234</text>
    <text width="1" height="1"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <text>TOTAL</text>
    <feed unit="12"/>
    <feed line="3"/>
    .
    .
    .
<Data>
```

My problem here is that I don't know how many `<text>` & `<feed>` will be there at what order.

Is it possible to create such XML using JAXB?

I am using following class but I can't get the `<text>` after `<feed>`

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
public class Data {
    private List<Text> text;
    private List<Feed> feed;

    @XmlElement(name = "text")
    public List<Text> getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(List<Text> text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "feed")
    public List<Feed> getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(List<Feed> feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for the solution for few days later I ended up using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/)